# codeigniter route showing parent directory page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I defined route in codeigniter as shown

```
$route['tutor'] = 'login/tutor_login';
```

And url becomes tutor.xyz.com/tutor. It is working fine on local server(localhost/tutor/tutor) but when I uploaded to domain then this url directs to a page which is showing page with parent directory folder with title index of /tutor/ when i click on parent directory it redirects to home. what can be possibly wrong so that I am getting this issue. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: how is your `$config['base_url']` setting?

Comment: You should share directory structure

Comment: i have changed base_url with the domain url when uploaded. other link tutor.xyz.com/admin is working fine but this is the only link which is not working

Comment: how about your htaccess? any difference? has your production site a https protocol? but most likeley you have a "localhost" setting somewhere instead of pointing to the domain

Comment: i get your point. but tutor.xyz.com/admin is working and /tutor is not. it is not showing error like no page found but somehow it redirect to a page which have this link named as parent directory when i clink it takes to home page.. if i had any problem with ht access or not changed base_url. admin shouldn't have open also

Comment: It may be a miscoded redirect. Could you post the `login/tutor_login` controller code and also sharing directory structure may helpful.

Comment: ok sure but i want to ask one thing. if there is something miscoded  or error of any kind then why it is working perfectly on localserver(xamp)